# Programmatically clear autofill fields in Chrome each time page is loaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, autofill

I have a page that uses JQuery and ajax on the front-end. There are fields and filters which a user can choose.

In internet explorer these fields are never pre-populated if a user reloads the page. In Chrome when the user reloads the page these autofill fields are already pre-populated.

Is there a way to clear the autofill fields in Chrome when the page is loaded?

I know the way to disable autofill in the browser by going to settings. However, I would like the solution to work for every user, not just users who disable autofill.

Comment: since you are using jquery already, you could try setting the value attr of the fields to " " during the document on load event

Comment: surely it's up to the user whether they use autofill or not? It's there for their convenience, and is really not of any concern to your application. Some users may find this very useful. Why would you want to cripple that? It will just annoy users who like the feature. Those who don't will already have turned it off or ignored it.

Comment: The issue is that there are lots of fields and filters and generally the type of search performed only needs to be done once. Users are getting confused because they are not realizing that filters are still pre-populated when coming to the page again... it looks like no data is being returned on searches. The Internet Explorer behavior is better for our particular use case.

Comment: Checkout the `autocomplete` property. https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/att_input_autocomplete.asp https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp

Comment: so they don't realise they have to click search again in order for it to take effect? Surely that's a training issue? Either to explain how it works (i.e. you have to click the button to apply the filters), or to tell them to disable autocomplete on that page because it isn't necessary. But yeah you should be able use the autocomplete attribute to help with this if necessary.